# Robot Framework - Selenium2Library - Choose File keyword with Edge Browser

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, microsoft-edge, selenium2library

I have created a test where a user will upload a file to the website by clicking on the "Choose File" button.

I am using the Choose File keyword and it works correctly within Firefox and Chrome. When it comes to Edge, it just sits there and doesn't respond. Thus failing the test. If I look at the log which is generated however it says the keyword passed correctly. (The error message which pops up is stopping the test from continuing - but Edge is stopping the keyword from working)

Is there a way round this? I need to get all three browsers working with this test.

Just for reference here is the line I am using:

```
Choose File    name=file    C:\\Users\\John\\Test.txt
```

Comment: nice question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately this is not going to work for Edge just yet as sendKeys is not implemented and the Choose File keyword is harnassing this ability.  More information on what is and isn't implemented can be found here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/webdriver-commands/

Comment: Cheers for the link - ill keep up-to-date with it

Comment: awesome, really appreciated